# Can we concat as well as replace string values in SQL Server (SSMS)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: NAMES_TABLE]

I executed below query, but I got result as null values.

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(FIRST_NAME,'null',''),'N/A',''),'no',''),'NA','') +' ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LAST_NAME,'null',''),'N/A',''),'no',''),'NA','')) AS 'FULL_NAME' FROM NAMES
```

Instead I want my output to be:

```
FULL_NAME
___________
Ankit Kumar
Mayank Sharma
Puneet Kumar
Rajesh
Narender
Robert
Chahuhan
Jaswinder Singh
Rakesh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more recent versions of SQL Server support `concat_ws()`:

```
select concat_ws(' ', 
                 (case when first_name not in ('na', 'no', 'null') then first_name end),
                 (case when last_name not in ('na', 'no', 'null') then last_name end)
                ) as full_name
```

In older versions, you can use:

```
select ltrim( (case when first_name not in ('na', 'no', 'null') then ' ' + first_name else '' end) +
              (case when last_name not in ('na', 'no', 'null') then ' ' + last_name else '' end)
            ) as full_name
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,your query worked thank you for quick response.